# Script/Daemon to kill specific resource-consuming tools?

Tags: kill, top, cluster

I'm working on a SGE linux cluster and beginners often run memory/resource consuming tools on the login node instead of using `qsub` or `qlogin` ( https://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html ) .

Is there any tool or method to kill some specific programs (like [bwa](https://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/)) if they have been running on the login node for more than, say, 5 minutes  ?